# Error when customize ValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i want to customize ValidationMessageFor which display error. when i run application, a get an error : 
**No overload for method 'ValidationMessageFor' takes 1 arguments**

I'm understand my error, but i don't know how to fix it ?
I need some suggest . Thanks you for reading!

My code :

```
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OurCompanyUI.app_code
{
    public static class MyHtml
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(
                                        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                                        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                                        string validationMessage,
                                        IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
                                    )
        {
            string modelName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            TagBuilder p = new TagBuilder("p");
            p.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(htmlHelper,expression).ToString();
         //   p.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor().ToString();
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(p.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)); 
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have brought the namespace into which the original `ValidationMessageFor` helper is defined into scope by adding the following to your using directives:

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

Comment: i used System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor . it belong to System.Web.Mvc.Html which you suggest. but i don't fix error. Can you explain this code :`Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,` , plz ? thanks you!

Comment: What error? Just add the using as shown in my answer and then the `htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString()` call will work. If you want to use `System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor` (which IMHO is the wrong way to use an extension method) you need to pass the htmlHelper as first argument: `p.InnerHtml = System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor(htmlHelper, expression).ToString();`.

Comment: i used the first way, which you suggest for me. but i didn't understand that where ValidationMessageFor belong to ? . I think that, it is Method of System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.  you suggest me that using System.Web.Mvc.Html ???  Sorry, my english is not verry good . ^^!

Comment: i'm using visual 2012. i try this above code with visual 2010. my code is hasn't got any error  ????

Comment: @user1542080, `ValidationMessageFor` is an extension method to the HtmlHelper class that is defined inside the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace. Please read about extension methods in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx That's why you should add `using System.Web.Mvc.Html` to your file - in order to bring this extension method into scope.

Comment: DImitrow : thanks you verry much! i fixed it. have you got nick twitter ?